# Design magento2 theme with css instead of Less

Tags: magento2, css, less

i can add my custom css and over-ride theme's defaut css etc, Can i go this way and not use LESS.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,500italic,600,600italic|Indie+Flower|Dosis" src_type="url" /> 
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />

  </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this, you can just add a custom url to you static CSS file, but im not sure why you want to do this...

What i did is i kept the default less/css from magento and made my own vendor.less / vendor.css thats overrides some, but generally adds just my own css

Comment: i am not aware of Less structure so i want to design it using bootstrap based css and not use LESS in theme

Comment: also kay i have question reqgaridng M2 as i see major difference here and the process in m2 is complex from M1 as need to go to CMD every time to do stuff, so do major of people willing to switch from m1 to m2? is that good or bad what do you suggest?

Comment: Yes, Magento2 is a lot more complex, and is build with way more modern techniques. You can use Bootstrap and less if you want combined of course. It sounds a little that you are taking a shortcut... There is a lot of CMD-line stuff involved in developing with Magento2. So if your not comfortable i should really re-consider to dive in. I'm very experienced in M1, and also pretty much in Back-end and front-end development, and it has been already a huge journey. So would i advice, yes if you have the knowledge or time to get it.  ;-) Good luck!

Comment: i am not a m1 expert but using commands that are given in m2 document i can do few theme stuff and it reflects, How long do you think it takes to learn M2? with db structure and extension and theming?

Comment: That depends so much on your basic php and frond-end skill-level. Im working for 3 months with it now, and have a good understanding but still mis a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with Twitter Bootstrap, you could start by using the LESS version of Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/2.0.4/less.html

It would be something you are already familiar with so the learning curve wouldn't be as steep and would allow you to spend more time learning other areas of Magento 2